Jpeg being resized when saving on Illustrator
I created a file on an artboard sized 4" x 2.5" however when I export it as a jpeg it resizes to 3.9" x 2.69".  I am exporting at 72ppi with baseline optimized compression and Type Optimized (hinted) for anti-aliasing.  The Quality is set at 8.
Why is this happening and how do I fix this?  I need to export a jpeg of the file so that I can paste it onto another file I'm working on that has multiple 4" x 2.5" jpegs going onto it.




Are your numbers correct here? Your image not only change in size, but also aspect ratio (width decreases but height increases)?

Impossible to say without seeing your export options. If you have bleed in your artwork, using Export -> Export As will include the bleed in the exported file unless you check Use Artboards. But I do not think this would cause the size issue you say you have.

Yes, my numbers are correct which is why I am so confused as well.  It is cutting off the right side edge of my image and adding a white space at the top of my image that is not on the artboard and I do not have any bleed settings.

That was a typo - my numbers are correct.  I've posted screencaps of what I am seeing and what my save settings are.  The artboard shows as 4" x 2.5" and I have no bleed settings, but the image the is saved converts to 3.9" x 2.69" which is both the wrong sizing and wrong dimensions

See if checking "Use Artboards" in the export dialog box helps.

